# NextAuth: no need for signup/signin distinction in UI?

Tags: authentication, user-interface, next-auth

Noob question about NextAuth and its easy-to-use providers like Google, GitHub, and Email.

If I have an authentication page that only offers options like *Google*, *GitHub*, and *Email*, does this mean that I don't need the to distinguish between *signin* and *signup* in the UI? After all, these providers always follow the same default behavior when clicked.

I ask because I can't seem to recall examples of websites where there's no such distinction in the UI. There's always a pair of *sign in / sign up* tabs, although that may be because most websites also offer credentials login *(email/username+password)* as an option, in which case the distinction does matter.